# Twilio Media Streams - Twilio is not connecting to my websocket server

Tags: python, websocket, twilio

I'm currently developing an application using Twilio Media Streams to process audio data in real-time. However, I'm encountering an issue where the call disconnects immediately after making a POST request to the /voice endpoint.

Here are the details of my setup:

1. I am using Flask to host my application and Flask-Sockets to handle WebSocket connections.
2. My /voice endpoint returns a TwiML response with the  verb to start a media stream. The WebSocket URL in the TwiML response is wss://my-ngrok-subdomain.ngrok.io/stream.
3. My WebSocket server is running and accessible from the internet. I have confirmed this by testing the WebSocket connection independently of Twilio using a WebSocket client.
4. I have enabled detailed logging in my application and WebSocket server, but I have not found any errors or issues that could explain why the call is disconnecting / why Twilio is not connecting to my websocket.

Despite these measures, the call still disconnects immediately after making the POST request to the /voice endpoint. I have checked the Twilio logs, and they end on making the request to /voice. There are no logs indicating that Twilio is attempting to connect to my WebSocket.

Here is the relevant part of my WebSocket server code:

```
def handle_audio(ws):
    logging.info('Handling audio')  # Added logging
    while not ws.closed:
        message = ws.receive()
        if message is None:
            logging.info("No message received...")
            continue

        # Messages are a JSON encoded string
        data = json.loads(message)

        # Using the event type you can determine what type of message you are receiving
        if data['event'] == "connected":
            logging.info("Connected Message received: {}".format(message))
        elif data['event'] == "start":
            logging.info("Start Message received: {}".format(message))
        elif data['event'] == "media":
            logging.info("Media message: {}".format(message))
            payload = data['media']['payload']
            logging.info("Payload is: {}".format(payload))
            audio_data = base64.b64decode(payload)
            logging.info("That's {} bytes".format(len(audio_data)))

            # Split the audio data on silence
            audio_chunks = whisper_handler.split_on_silence(audio_data)
            logging.info('Split audio data into %d chunks', len(audio_chunks))  # Added logging

            # Transcribe each audio chunk
            transcriptions = [whisper_handler.transcribe_audio(chunk) for chunk in audio_chunks]
            logging.info('Transcribed audio chunks: %s', transcriptions)  # Added logging
        elif data['event'] == "closed":
            logging.info("Closed Message received: {}".format(message))
            break
```

I would appreciate any assistance you could provide in resolving this issue. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to add:

```
response.say("hello! how can I help!", voice='women')
response.pause(length=60)
```

So that my code now looks like this:

```
@app.route('/voice', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
    response = VoiceResponse()

    # Use the <Start> verb to start a Media Stream
    start = Start()
    start.stream(name='My Audio Stream', url='wss://subdomain.ngrok-free.app/stream')  # Added name
    
    response.append(start)  # Append the Start object to the VoiceResponse object

    response.say("hello! how can I help!", voice='women')
    response.pause(length=60)

    # Return a Response object with the Content-Type header set to application/xml
    return Response(str(response), mimetype='application/xml')
```

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. To add some context, Twilio only streams the audio as long as the call is running. If the call is immediately terminated, the WS connection is also terminated right away and might not even complete the initial connection if the time window is too small.